# How to get more than one json element from a cURL call using jq?

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I am trying to gather multiple json fields from a curl call in the command line. I have only been able to get one field at a time, each time it requires me to redo the curl call. For example, if there are two fields `field_1` and `field_2` under a `parent` field, I am having to do:

```
curl "https://www.somewebsite.com" | jq -r '.parent | .field_1'
```

and

```
curl "https://www.somewebsite.com" | jq -r '.parent | .field_2'
```

which is inefficient since the curl call already contains all piece of information. How can I gather both fields in just one curl call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just separate them with commas:

```
url "https://www.somewebsite.com" | jq -r '.parent | .field_1, .field_2'
```